# Regex: Find delimiters more than N chars apart

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-greedy

I want to split sentences at commas, but only if there's more than 36 charactes between the last match and the next comma.

So, Input:

> Hello World Hello World, Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello
>   World, Hello World, Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World
>   Hello World, Hello World Hello World Hello World.

Output:

> Hello World Hello World, Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello
>   World,
>
> Hello World, Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello World Hello
>   World,
>
> Hello World Hello World Hello World.

Using regex, `(.){36,}(, )` will find a block that's the start of the sentence up to the final matching string. `(, )(.){36,}(, )` will find a long middle section of a paragraph. But I want to find each matching sting in a paragraph in turn.

Can regex do this? I'm using the N++ flavour.

Comment: Try `(.{37,}?),` and replace with `$1\n` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/zO5mR5/1))

Answer (score 0):

Rather than splitting you can do a match using:

```
(.{36,}?), *
```

`(.{36,}?)` matches 36 or more characters lazily. You can store captured group #1 in your array.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hO0aQ0/1)